# How to iterate through a count in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an integer value being passed to my template, and I want to create a number of html elements equal to that integer.

game.players is a number 0-10.

I want to create a number of input elements equal to the count of game.players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either populate the context with an iterable or define a [template filter that handles a number input and outputs an iterable](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/).

Note: it's recommended to define the iterable in your view as that's the django philosophy and why there's no built in range filter.

[Here's what a core dev thinks:](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13088)

> My impression of this idea is that it
>   is trying to lead to programming in
>   the template. If you have a list of
>   options that need to be rendered, they
>   should be computed in the view, not in
>   the template. If that's as simple as a
>   range of values, then so be it.

```
# view
for game in games:
    game.players_range = range(game.players)

return render_to_response("foo.html", {'games': games})


# template
{% for game in games %}
    {% for i in game.players_range %}
      Element {{ i }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In my scenario, I know only the number of potential players in a game, and want to display a number of player name entry fields equal to the maximum number of potential players.  So it's not like I'm pushing any programming to the template.  But I digress - a custom filter is need for my case.